# how to loop through a list of lists in python

Tags: python, loops, nested

need to loop through list of lists and test if the string is either black or red and then add or subtract from the float in the list - e.g add 1 if "Black" or subtract 1 if string value is "Red"

```
new_line = [["Black", 3.0], ["Red", 7.0], ["Red", 2.0], ["Black", 3.5]]

for i in new line:
    if value == "Black":
          add =+ 1 to float value (3.0 in first example)
    else: 
          subtract -=1 float value (7.0 in second value n list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
new_line = [["Black", 3.0], ["Red", 7.0], ["Red", 2.0], ["Black", 3.5]]

for i in new_line:
     if i[0] == "Black":
          i[1] += 1.0
     else: 
          i[1] -= 1.0

 print(new_line)
```

Comment: Thank you v much.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close. This should do it:

```
new_line = [["Black", 3.0], ["Red", 7.0], ["Red", 2.0], ["Black", 3.5]]

for i in new_line:
    if i[0] == "Black":
          i[1] += 1
    else: 
          i[1] -=1
```

Comment: Thank you. Also Sam. Pierre just pipped you in the response. Many thanks J.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
new_line = [[color,value+(color=="Black")*2-1] for color,value in new_line]
```